# How to make Make Custom Arrays.asList in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a code for an expandable view in android which is loading limited data into the adapter. I want to customize the data and I am stuck with Arrays.asList() syntax.

Here is the code for loading data now:

```
    public static List<Genre> makeGenres()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(makeRockGenre(),
                makeJazzGenre(),
                makeClassicGenre(),
                makeSalsaGenre(),
                makeBluegrassGenre());
    }


    public static Genre makeRockGenre()
    {
        return new Genre("Rock", makeRockArtists(), R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_24dp);
    }

    public static List<Artist> makeRockArtists()
    {
        Artist queen = new Artist("Queen", true);
        Artist styx = new Artist("Styx", false);
        Artist reoSpeedwagon = new Artist("REO Speedwagon", false);
        Artist boston = new Artist("Boston", true);

        return Arrays.asList(queen, styx, reoSpeedwagon, boston);
    }
```

Note:-rest of the  similar methods have been skipped here.

As you can see **makeGenres()** returns a list which is being created through Arrays.asList(). Here ArraysasList is calling five methods inside each of which returns an array.  What I wanna do is instead of calling these five methods, I wanna Create Arrays.asList() with **'n'** number of arrays.

I need something which will do like this:

```
public static List<Genre> makeGenres()
{
        return MakeArrayAsList();
}

public static List<Genre> MakeArrayAsList()
{

     for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
     {

     //add 20 array items like this
     newGenre("Rock",makeRockArtists(),R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_24dp);
     }

//make Array.asList() using those 20 items to return
 // return Arrays.asList  

}
```

Basically, as if I can call makeRockGenre() **'n'** times inside **Arrays.asList** rather than the five methods in original code.

Comment: Can you use an `ArrayList`, `add` all the elements and then return the `ArrayList`?

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `Arrays.asList` with a dynamic number of arguments?

`Arrays.asList` is variadic, so we can pass an array into it:

```
public static List<Genre> MakeArrayAsList() {
    Genre[] genres = new Genre[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        //add 20 array items like this
        genres[i] = newGenre("Rock",makeRockArtists(),R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_24dp);
    }
    //make Array.asList() using those 20 items to return
    // return Arrays.asList  
    return Arrays.asList(genres);
}
```

But you might not actually want to use `Arrays.asList`.
What do you really want?

Comment: Thank You. This fixed the issue although i had to make a small tweak - "  Genre[] genres = new Genre[20];"